# generic method - call method different class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to set to variable result method from first class or second class which depend from type, what is wrong in my code??

```
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = GetValue(new ClassOne(), "classOne");

        return View();
    }



    public string GetValue<T>(T customClass, string type)
    {
        if (type == "classOne") return customClass.ClassOneMethod();
        else customClass.ClassTwoMethod();
    }

    class ClassOne
    {
        public string ClassOneMethod()
        {
            return "ClassOneMethod";
        }
    }

    class ClassTwo
    {
        public string ClassTwoMethod()
        {
            return "ClassTwoMethod";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why both classes do not implement an interface by doing something different and `GetValue` is something like `string GetValue(ISomeInterface obj) { obj.DoSomething(); }`?

Comment: Well, what does the compiler say?

Comment: The compiler is probably unable to figure out if `customClass` of type `T` has methods called `ClassOneMethod` and `ClassTwoMethod`.

Comment: By the way, deciding which method to call based on a string is not really elegant and calls for trouble in the form of typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler knows nothing about type `T` at compile time and is unable to figure out that the object contained in `customClass` has a method called `ClassOneMethod` or `ClassTwoMethod`. You have several options, for example deriving from a common base class overriding a virtual method or implementing an interface.

Here some hints on how to do it using an interface. This is far from perfect but I tried to keep it quite close to your original code.

```
interface IHaveAMethod
{
    String GetString();
}

public ActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewBag.Message = GetValue(new ClassOne());

    return View();
}

public String GetValue<T>(T customClass) where T : IHaveAMethod
{
    return customClass.GetString();
}

class ClassOne : IHaveAMethod
{
    public String GetString()
    {
        return "ClassOneMethod";
    }
}

class ClassTwo : IHaveAMethod
{
    public String GetString()
    {
        return "ClassTwoMethod";
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for `GetValue` to be generic, just have the parameter be an instance of `IHaveAMethod`.

Comment: Right. There is probably no need for the method `GetValue<T>` in the first place, but - as stated - I tried to keep the code close to the question to cause not to much confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work because your classes don't have an equal definition. You could change your code like this to get your code running:

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewBag.Message = GetValue<MyInterface>(new ClassOne());
    return View();
}

public string GetValue<T>(T customClass, string type)
{
    return customClass.MyMethod
}

class ClassOne : IMyInterface
{
    public string MyMethod()
    {
        return "ClassOneMethod";
    }
}

class ClassTwo : IMyInterface
{
    public string MyMethod()
    {
        return "ClassTwoMethod";
    }
}

public Interface IMyInterface
{
    string MyMethod();
}
```